# Dynammic Programming

Tags: dynamic-programming

Can anyone explain to me the solution to the Longest Common Subsequence Problem? Specifically, the recurrence relation is

if(x<sub>i</sub>=y<sub>j</sub>) then answer= max<sub>L</sub>(i-1, j-1) +1

else answer=Max{Max<sub>L</sub>(i-1, j), Max<sub>L</sub>(i, j-1)}

x<sub>i</sub> / y<sub>i</sub> is the letter in the constructed table. Max<sub>L</sub> corresponds to the entry in the table constructed.

My question is why is the answer maxL(i-1,j-1) + 1? Why do we have to add from the upper left diagonal only when the letters match?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(xi=yj) in recurrence relation means both the string have same characters at their respective current position.

Lets take a simple example:

Consider the input strings **AGGTAB** and **GXTXAYB**.

Last characters `'B'` match for both the strings.[*That is xi==yj condition holds*].

So length of LCS can be written as:

```
LCS("AGGTAB", "GXTXAYB") = 1 + LCS("AGGTA", "GXTXAY")
```

LCS("AGGTA", "GXTXAY") is stored in Table[i−1,j −1] (ie. max<sub>L</sub>[i-1][j-1])

Comment: You, my friend, are a boss.